# How to enable default compatibility mode for my site ie10

Tags: internet-explorer

My website is running good on all browsers. but in ie its disturbed. But when i click on compatibility mode then its looks perfect. Is there any way that my website always open in compatibility mode for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.  According to http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/p/x-ua-compatible-meta-tag.htm,

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

will force IE into behaving as IE8 (also available, 9, 10 etc).  There are a whole host of compatibility modes, and you may have to experiment to find the right one.